# Save changes button doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql

I'm still making the orderform, I've been working on the "save changes function". 
By this I mean, if people make changes to the table, they can click on a button and it will update the database (where I get my data from).

[image: Screenshot]

"Bestelling toevoegen" is the adding form, if I fill in the form, and click on "Toevoegen" it will display a new record to the table above.

The problem is, I can't seem to save the changes (Wijzigigen opslaan) of "Status".

Here's the full code:

```
    $dbname = "localhost";
    $dblogin = "root";
    $dbpass = "";
    $dbtable = "bestelformulier";

    $con=mysqli_connect("$dbname","$dblogin","$dbpass","$dbtable");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM overzicht");

    echo "<form name='wijzigen' method='post'>";
    echo "<table align='center' width='700px' border='2'>
    <tr>
    <th>Ordernr</th>
    <th>Klantnaam</th>
    <th>Productnaam</th>
    <th>ProductID</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    </tr>";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {

    $ordernr = $row['ordernr'];
    $klantnaam = $row['klantnaam'];
    $productnaam = $row['productnaam'];
    $productid = $row['productid'];

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $ordernr . "</td>";
    echo "<td width='150px'>" . $klantnaam . "</td>";
    echo "<td width='200px'>" . $productnaam . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $productid . "</td>";

    echo "<td><select name='status'>
      <option>" . $row['status'] . "</option>";
      if($row['status']  != "Niet besteld")
      echo "<option value='Niet besteld'>Niet besteld</option>";
      if($row['status']  != "Besteld")
      echo "<option value='Besteld'>Besteld</option>";
      if($row['status']  != "Onderweg naar hoofdlocatie")
      echo "<option value='Onderweg naar hoofdlocatie'>Onderweg naar hoofdlocatie</option>";
      if($row['status']  != "Onderweg naar vestiging")
      echo "<option value='Onderweg naar vestiging'>Onderweg naar vestiging</option>";
      if($row['status']  != "Ontvangen")
      echo "<option value='Ontvangen'>Ontvangen</option>";
    echo "</select></td>";

    echo "</tr>";

    }
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='submit' name='wijzigen' value='Wijzigingen Opslaan'/></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";
    echo "</form>";

    $status = $_POST['status'];

    if(isset($_POST['wijzigen'])) {
    $query = mysqli_query("UPDATE overzicht SET status='$status' WHERE ordernr='$ordernr'");
    }

    mysqli_close($con);

    //Table Toevoegen
    $con=mysqli_connect("$dbname","$dblogin","$dbpass","$dbtable");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    echo "<br/><br/><br/>";
    echo "<h5>Bestelling Toevoegen</h5>";
    echo "<form name='toevoegen' method='post'>";
    echo "<table width='700px' border='1'>

    <tr>
    <th>klantnaam</th>
        <td><input type='text' name='klantnaam'/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <th>Productnaam</th>
        <td><input type='text' name='productnaam'/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <th>productid</th>
        <td><input type='text' name='productid'/></td>
    </tr>



    <tr>
       <th>Status</th>
       <td>
         <select name='statusinfo'>
           <option value='Niet besteld'>Niet besteld</option>
           <option value='Besteld'>Besteld</option>
           <option value='Onderweg naar hoofdlocatie'>Onderweg naar hoofdlocatie</option>
           <option value='Onderweg naar vestiging'>Onderweg naar vestiging</option>
           <option value='Ontvangen'>Ontvangen</option>
         <select>
       </td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type='submit' name='toevoegen' value='Toevoegen'/></td>
    </tr>";


    echo "</table>";


    $klantnaam = $_POST['klantnaam'];
    $productnaam = $_POST['productnaam'];
    $productid = $_POST['productid'];
    $statusinfo = $_POST['statusinfo'];

    if(isset($_POST['toevoegen'])) {

    $query = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO overzicht (klantnaam, productnaam, productid, status)
    VALUES ('$klantnaam', '$productnaam', '$productid', '$statusinfo')");

    $current_url = (empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "http://" : "https://") . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    header ('Location: ' . $current_url);
    exit ();
    }
    echo "</form>";
    mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: Are you having problems with your `UPDATE` or your `INSERT`? Because you have two different `<select>` in regards to `status` --- `<select name='status'>` and `<select name='statusinfo'>`

Comment: Can you tell if `status` and `wijzigen` are being recognized as set by your script? Do a `print $status` and `print $_POST['wijzigen']` right after you set `$status = $_POST['status'];` and let me know if that's working.  If those are showing up as expected, then try printing out 'mysqli_error()' after you run your update query.

Comment: A couple things. 1. You are wide open to SQL injection attacks. 2. Why do you close and then re-establish the same mysqli connection after a query? 3. You try and do an update in the middle of a loop through your table.  You need to have the row id or something available from the post and then update the record based on that and the status - not during the display loop as you have it now.

Comment: @Fred-ii- UPDATE is the problem.

Comment: You have two named form elements with the same name `input type='submit' name='wijzigen'` and `<form name='wijzigen'` try removing the (name) one for `<form name='wijzigen'` there could be a conflict. @user2966741

Comment: @Quixrick I am seeing "Onderweg naar hoofdlocatieOnderweg naar hoofdlocatie" when I print it

Comment: @Jon "3. You try and do an update in the middle of a loop through your table. " I don't think that's the case since I actually ended my loop and THEN wrote the mysql code.. or am I wrong?

Comment: @user2966741 You are still taking your ID from the end of that loop - not from anything that was submitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are having problems because you are outputting multiple `select` elements that all have the name `status`.  Try changing this line:

```
echo "<td><select name='status'>
```

to:

```
echo "<td><select name='status[$ordernr]'>
```

Then you will have an array of status with the keys being the order number.  Then change this:

```
$status = $_POST['status'];

if(isset($_POST['wijzigen'])) {
$query = mysqli_query("UPDATE overzicht SET status='$status' WHERE ordernr='$ordernr'");
}
```

to:

```
$statuses = $_POST['status'];

if(isset($_POST['wijzigen'])) {
    foreach($statuses as $ordernr => $status)
    {
        if($status != "")
            $query = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE overzicht SET status='$status' WHERE ordernr='$ordernr'");
    }
}
```

Comment: I have changed my code to yours, but still no success.. doesnt save

Comment: Inside this if: `if(isset($_POST['wijzigen'])) {` do `var_dump($statuses)` and output what this gives you

Comment: array(2) {
[40]=>
string(26) “Onderweg naar hoofdlocatie”
[41]=>
string(23) “Onderweg naar vestiging”
}
array(2) {
[40]=>
string(26) “Onderweg naar hoofdlocatie”
[41]=>
string(23) “Onderweg naar vestiging”
}

Comment: I just got 2 records, ordernr 40 and 41 at this very moment

Comment: Change `$query = mysqli_query("UPDATE ...` to `$query = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE ...` as I have done in my answer

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
$query = mysqli_query("UPDATE overzicht SET status='$status' WHERE ordernr='$ordernr'");
```

Your `$ordernr` is empty. If you want to update an existing record, you have to pass the ordernr via GET or POST along the form.

However, your form design allows only one order status to be updated at the same time. You should either pass all ordernrs and their status as array, or do it via AJAX.

Also, read up about SQL injection. If this code goes productive, your database will be hacked, guaranteed.

Comment: Could you give me an example of how you would do it?

Comment: You need two things: Pass the ordernr back to the script with your form by placing a hidden element: `<input type="hidden" name="ordernr" value="PUT_ORDERNR_HERE_WHEN_GENERATING_FORM" />` and then, on the server side, read the ordernr: `$ordernr = $_POST['ordernr']`. But note the other answer here. It won't work properly, because you have only one form and one status and one ordernr for many different orders. If you don't understand this at first, try to make a form that updates only one single order status and learn from that.